# Output least number of slices required to sort an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to output the number of slices required to slice an unsorted array of n distinct integers into one or more slices and sort them so that when the sorted slices are joined back (in the same order), it gives the original array in the sorted order.

For example,

Given array = [2,1,6,4,3,7]

If you slice the given array like this : [2,1] [6,4,3] [7] Then sort these individually like this: [1,2] [3,4,6] [7] And finally, join them back like this : [1,2,3,4,6,7] You get the original array in sorted order. So, the number of slices is 3

I tried to search it in Stack Overflow/Google and found the following solution but it doesn't seem to work for the above input (returns 2 instead of 3).

```
public int solution(int[] A)
{
    if (A.Length < 3) return A.Length;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < A.Length; i++)
    {
         if (A[i] > A[i - 1]) count += 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Can anyone suggest how can we approach this problem and appropriately solve this in C#

Comment: What does it mean to sort the slices and then join them back in the same order? Why should that example give the result of 3?

Comment: If you slice the given array like this : [2,1] [6,4,3] [7]
Then sort these individually like this: [1,2] [3,4,6] [7]
And finally, join them back like this : [1,2,3,4,6,7] 
You get the original array in sorted order.
So, the number of slices is 3.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that description. The fact that you want the function to return the number of slices is nowhere in the original question.

Comment: @Moh Why not slice the given array into one slice  [2,1,6,4,3,7], sort it to [1,2,3,4,6,7], and... there is no joining needed? Is there another constraint which I can't see in the question?

Comment: You're ignoring the null case of 1 slice, so start with `count = 1` instead of `count = 0`.

Comment: I thought the same, but my guess is the only operation allowed to the slices is leave as they are or flip back to forth.

Comment: @DStanley Thanks! This works and I understood the mistake as well.

Comment: @Mocas If you're replying to me, I was wondering the same, but do you think there is some constraint that disallows the initial array being something like [3,1,6,4,2,7]?

Comment: @Andrew, yes, sorry forget to tag you. I was only guessing, and if my guess is right, the only valid two cases where the whole array can be one slice are when it is already ordered asc or desc. Obviously there is no constraint on your initial array, but the constraint is on what can be a valid slice, which is it has to be possible just to attach it to other slices without sorting, and only flipping is allowed. Again, this is only a guess :D

Comment: The concept of a slice means you need to consider how you can subdivide the original array, while keeping the "join them in the original order" criteria. So you need to make sure that all elements in the rest of the array are not in-between the elements you've seen so far. Let me rephrase. You say the original input of `2,1,6,4,3,7` can be subdivided into `2,1` - `6,4,3` - `7`, sorted to `1,2` - `3,4,6` - `7`, and then rejoined. OK, but what if the input array was `2,1,6,4,3,7,0`. The code in your question has nothing to handle that kind of thing, so this is more complex than you think.

Comment: Even the first if-statement is incorrect. `if (A.Length < 3) return A.Length;`? This would handle `2,1` = 2 slices, but it would be incorrect for `1,2` = 1 slice (already sorted).

Answer (score 0):

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    int l = A.length;
    if (l < 3) return l;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < l; i++) {
        if (A[i] > A[i - 1]) count += 1;
    }
    if (A[l - 1] > A[l - 2]) {
        count += 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.